# Is the huge white metal grille on a ceiling called a "cassette AC". Is it supposed to be noisy?

Tags: air-conditioning

I am looking to buy a house, but i'm worried about the AC noise. It has the compressor outside the house. The evaporator coil is inside the attic on top of the furnace. This attic is above the laundry.

So, every room has a little (around 10 by 5 inches) white metal grille on the ceilings to push the air in.

**But the hallway ceiling has a huge (around 30 by 50 inches) white metal grille. Is it called a "cassette AC". Why is it so noisy ? What does it do ?**

Maybe this is the normal noise level. I don't know. I can't ask my realtor, 'coz she will assure me everything is fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the return air grille, where the AC's air handler sucks up air to cool that it pushes through the ceiling registers in the other rooms. Central return systems are inherently noisy, but good duct design can alleviate this to a certain extent as can using a smaller blower motor if the ductwork was done well enough that the reduced airflow speed doesn't result in worse air delivery.

Your bigger problem is the fact that your air conditioner is in the attic, where it will get to be like 140 degrees. I bet every time it kicks on, all the rooms get blasted with a slug of hot air for a few seconds, right?

Comment: Thank you. When you say `Central return systems are inherently noisy`, do you mean there are other options ? Are there any quiet systems ?

Comment: More like there are ways to design an AC ductwork system to be quieter. One is having many returns. Another is properly balancing the supply and return parts of the system. Still another one is making sure there aren't any hard right angles in the a central return duct very close to the air handler. Yet another is making sure the blower isn't oversized or vibrating. The easiest one of all might be cleaning the filter or replacing it with a cheap one that filters less. Lots of options. Hard to tell which one(s) would fix your problem without a lot more info.

Comment: Great followup question. Balanced returns are typically almost silent. In the homes I've lived in with central air, you only knew it was working because it was cool. We never heard it unless the house was completely devoid of other ambient sound.